# Laravel join two table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two table namely View table and Click Table as like below

```
id  View_count  Created_at
1   10         January
2   20         Febrauary
3   30          March

id  Click_count Created_at
1   20          January
2   40           March
3   30            May
```

I want to get count data based on month. By query i want to get table information as like below.

```
Created_at  View_count  Click_count
January         10         20
Febrauary       20  
March           30         40
May             30
```

I have tried as like this:

```
$view_count= View::select(DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
        ->orderBy("created_at")
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(created_at)"))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $view_count= array_column($view_count, 'count');

$click_count= Click::select(DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
        ->orderBy("created_at")
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("month(created_at)"))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $click_count= array_column($click_count, 'count');


 $count_bymonth =  View::select(DB::raw('MONTHName(created_at) as month'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw(' MONTH(created_at)'))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $count_bymonth  = array_column($count_bymonth , 'month');


 return view('testing')
       ->with('view_count', json_encode($view_count, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))
        ->with('click_count', json_encode($click_count, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))
        ->with('count_bymonth', json_encode($count_bymonth, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

If anyone know answer for this please do let me know as soon as possible.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in one query

```
$result = View::join('Click','Click.Created_at','=','View.Created_at')
          ->select(
           'Click_count.Created_at'
           DB::raw('SUM(Click_count) as Click_count'),
           DB::raw('SUM(View_count) as View_count')
          )
          ->groupBy('Click.Created_at')
          ->orderBy("created_at")
          ->get();

return view('testing')->with('result');
```

Then all you have to do is to loop the `result`.

Comment: can we get number of counts from two table with unique date?

Comment: did you try the code? Is that a new question? or still related to this question?

Comment: i tried sir but not able to get expected result. i want to get count of data based on month from two tables

Answer (score 0):

use laravel query builder joins

```
DB::table('View')
            ->join('Click', 'View.Created_at', '=', 'Click.Created_at')->get();
```

Comment: how get data by month wise data by using above query?

Comment: how do you insert to created_at ? timestamp or just the month?

Comment: it's a timestamp.